# How to get the current row in a Kendo context menu?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo context menu for a Kendo grid. I want to extract value of current row.
This is my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Class>()
    .Name("reqRows")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.0);
    })
)

@(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
    .Name("brc")
    .Target("#reqRows")
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("1").LinkHtmlAttributes(new { onClick = "confirm()" });
    })
)

<script>
    function confirm(e) {
        alert(e);
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        alert(dataItem.0);
    }
</script>
```

I get `Undefined` value for `e`. How can I extract the current row? And can I extract `Model.Id`, which is not bound in columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Select` event:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
    .Name("brc")
    .Target("#reqRows")
    .Items(items =>
    {
      items.Add().Text("1");
    })
    .Events(e => e.Select("selectItem"))
)
```

Then get the selected item like this:

```
function selectItem(e) {
    var grid = $(e.target).data("kendoGrid");
    var item = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    var data = item.SomeColumn;
}
```

If you open the context menu using the right mouse button, it won't select the row by default and `item` will be `undefined`. Add this javascript to ensure the row is selected (note that your grid will need to be `.Selectable()`):

```
$("#reqRows").on("mousedown", "tr[role='row']", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        $("#reqRows tbody tr").removeClass("k-state-selected");
        $(this).addClass("k-state-selected");
    }
});
```

If you want ID, you'll need to bind it to the grid. Just keep it hidden:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Class>()
    .Name("reqRows")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(x => x.SomeColumn);
    })
)
```

Comment: I still get an `undefined` for grid and the following error for item: `Unable to get property 'dataItem' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Hm, should work. What if you do: `var grid = $("#reqRows").data("kendoGrid");`?

Comment: Yeah, that did the job :) Any idea about the issue?

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work for you, it works for me at least. :) You can also try `var grid = $("#" + e.target.id).data("kendoGrid");`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, and there's no need for the code that adds/removes the k-state-selected class:

```
    function selectItem(e)
    {
        var item = e.sender.dataItem(e.target);

        alert(item.SomeColumn);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above approach only works when your grid has [`Ajax` binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DataSourceBuilder#methods-Ajax). When you have [`Server` binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DataSourceBuilder#methods-Server), the `$(e.target).data("kendoGrid")` is null/undefined.

In this case, I did the following:

1. Define a template in an column with some hidden fields:

   ```
   ...
   columns.Bound(pg => pg.FileName)
       .Title("My column")
       .Template(
           @<text>
               @* Store information for JS in hidden row fields. *@
               <input type="hidden" class="unique-id-hidden" value="@item.UniqueID" />

               @* Output the visible content. *@
               <div>
                   @item.FileName
               </div>
           </text>);
   ...
   ```
2. Later, in the `select` handler of the context menu, I do something like:

   ```
   function selectItem(e) {
       var uniqueID = $(e.target).closest("tr").find('.unique-id-hidden').first().val();

       // Do something with the data.
   }
   ```

To get the menu item that fired the event, you can use `$(e.item)`.